# Logging Success or Failure of a VBA code loop in the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, logging

I am trying to write a code that would be used to create folders (and sub folders) in a specific directory. The issue is that the folders may already exist in some cases. As such I want my code to start with a list in column "A" and for each item on the list if it's successful I want it to add a corresponding value in the same row of Column B that says "Done" and if it generates an error because the folder already existed, I want it to log the with "Already There". I have a functioning (I believe) version that does the creation part. It's the logging that I have yet to figure out.

I also wouldn't mind finding out a more simple version of just telling me how many times the current run generated an error. SO if I ran the code on a list of 100 items, it would first try to create a main folder and then a subfolder for each row, so if they all existed it would generate 200 errors.

The Code in it's current iteration:

```
Sub CreateFolders()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
Dim FldrRoot As String, FldrLvl1 As String, FldrLvl2 As String, FldrLvl3 As String, FileRef As String
Dim xDirectFldrRoot$, InitialFoldr$


InitialFoldr$ = "\\Filepath"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
.Title = "Please select the folder; subfolders will be created Automatically. "
.InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
.Show
If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
xDirectFldrRoot$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
Else

End If
End With



LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
FldrRoot = xDirectFldrRoot$

If Cells(1, 1).Value Like "*201*" Then i = 1 Else: i = 2


For n = i To LastRow

    FileRef = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Text   
                                        
    FldrLvl1 = Left(FileRef, 2) 
    FldrLvl2 = FileRef 
    
    
    On Error Resume Next 
    
    MkDir (FldrRoot & "\" & FldrLvl1) '//Create Level 1 folder (eg; 01)\\
    MkDir (FldrRoot & "\" & FldrLvl1 & "\" & FldrLvl2) '//Create Level 2 folder (eg; 01-211-0587878458)\\
    
    
    On Error GoTo 0 

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: You  can use `Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory)` to find out if the folder exists before trying to create it.  Or use the Scripting.FileSystemObject's `FolderExists()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub CreateFolders()

    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim FldrRoot As String, FldrLvl1 As String, FldrLvl2 As String
    Dim InitialFoldr As String, ws As Worksheet
    
    InitialFoldr = "\\Filepath"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
        .Title = "Please select the folder; subfolders will be created Automatically. "
        .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            FldrRoot = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        Else
            Exit Sub 'no folder chosen
        End If
    End With
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    i = IIf(ws.Cells(1, 1).Value Like "*201*", 1, 2)
    For n = i To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
        FldrLvl2 = ws.Range("A" & n).Text
        FldrLvl1 = Left(FldrLvl2, 2)

        'record result in cols B and C
        ws.Range("B" & n).Value = _
            IIf(CreateFolder(FldrRoot & FldrLvl1), "Created", "Existed")
        ws.Range("C" & n).Value = _
            IIf(CreateFolder(FldrRoot & FldrLvl1 & "\" & FldrLvl2), "Created", "Existed")
    Next
End Sub

'Returns True if the foler already exists, otherwise
'  returns False and creates the folder
'Assumes permissions are OK and folder name is valid
Function CreateFolder(folderPath As String) As Boolean
    CreateFolder = Len(Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0
    If CreateFolder Then MkDir folderPath
End Function
```